# Placing a button over an Image in a SharePoint webpart

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

Having difficulty styling a button in SharePoint webpart so that it is positioned over an image that is set dynamically.

HTML:

```
    <div id="nhaole-header-eloqua" class="imageArea">
    <img id="headerImage" src="<%=headerImageURL%>" />
    <div id="applyArea">
        <input id="applyNowBtn" type="button" value="Apply Now" class="applyButton" />
    </div></div>
```

CSS

```
        #headerImage {
        position:relative !important;
    }
    #applyArea {
        position:absolute !important;
         width: 100px !important;
         left:10% !important;
         top:50% !important;
    }
```

This sort of works until you scale the window and then button doesn't stay with the image.

Comment: write media query if you need to support multiple resolution. fix image width and height according to the screen

Answer (score 0):

I may have needed more coffee yesterday.

I found my own issue was that I needed to make the parent div relative

`#nhaole-header-eloqua {
        position:relative !important;
    }
    #applyArea {
        position:absolute !important;
         width: 100px !important;
         left:10% !important;
         top:50% !important;
    }`